# Expected mean of correlated data in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, math, statistics

I have successfully generated three correlated random variables with Cholesky. I use the same mean(10) and the same standard deviation(5) for all of them. However, I tried to calculate the expected mean of the correlated variables, but I got some an unpleasant results I can't seem to know where exactly the problem. Please here is a working code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
corr = np.array([[1,0.7,0.7], [0.7,1,0.7],[0.7,0.7,1]])
chol = np.linalg.cholesky(corr)
N=1000
rand_data = np.random.normal(10, 5, size=(3,N))

# generate uncorrelated data
uncorrelated_data = pd.DataFrame(rand_data, index=['A','B','C']).T/100
uncorrelated_data.corr()     # shows barely any correlation as it should
uncorrelated_data.mean()*100 # shows each mean around 10
```

Output

```
A    10.308595
B     9.931958
C    10.165347
```

Generating correlation among them

```
x = np.dot(chol, rand_data)     # cholesky
correlated_data = pd.DataFrame(x, index=['A','B','C']).T/100
print(correlated_data.corr()) # shows there are correlations among variable
sim_corr_rets.mean()*100      # mean keep increasing in across the variables
```

Output:

```
 A    10.308595
 B    14.308853
 C    16.752117
```

The means of the uncorrelated variables were as expected but the mean of the correlated variables keeps increasing from the first variable to the last variable. My expectation is that each mean will be around the actual mean. Please could my noble seniors help me figure out the problem or suggest an alternative solution?

Comment: `L . x` has a Gaussian distribution with mean 0 and variance `L . L'` when `x` is Gaussian with mean 0 and variance equal to the identity matrix. If you want to get a different mean, then add the mean after multiplying by `L` (the lower triangular Cholesky decomposition), i.e. `L . x + mu` has mean `mu`. I think the problem is that you need to subtract the mean before multiplying by `L` and then add it back in, i.e. `L . (x - mu) + mu`, since your `x` is not mean 0. You are effectively computing `L . x + L . mu` where `x` is mean 0.

Comment: By the way, this question is more conceptual than computational, so it's a better fit for stats.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: @RobertDodier, thank you so much for your submission. applying your suggestion i modified the line `x = np.dot(chol, rand_data)`  to `x = np.dot(chol, (rand_data-10))+10` and I got a reasonable estimates.